# Question mark in XML as value

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

In my android project I want to save under `string.xml` the value ?. I have found the code `&#63` that represents the question mark but it gives me an error "missing resource type". Could you help me, please?
XML Code:

```
<string name="questionMark">&#63;</string>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
 <string name="questionMark">\?</string>
```

and you can check this [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) to handle special characters.